# Why does boost::archive::binary_iarchive require a copyable argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-serialization

In this code:

```
class X {
   ...
   serialize(...)
   ...
};

void f() {
   X x;
   ifstream ifs(...);
   boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
   ia >> x;
}
```

Why does `X` have to be copyable, not just movable?

Comment: I didn't know this to be true. (I'd check that). Regardless, if true, it will probably have to do with C++03 history of the library

Comment: Just wanted to make sure there is no inherent reason for this before filing an enhancement request. Thanks.